# Problems storing a password programmatically in the crednetial store of WildFly, versions 17 and 21

Tags: java, security, wildfly, credentials

I am developing a JEE application running on WildFly 17 application server.

I want to store programmatically passwords in the credential store of WildFly following the steps in the link below:

https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/blob/main/credential-store/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/examples/CredentialStoreExample.java

Specifically, to store a password,  I use the line:

```
credentialStore.store("clearPassword", new PasswordCredential(clearPassword));
```

as shown in the above mentioned link at line 61

Altough the password is actually stored and I can access it programatically, whenever I restart the application server, the entry is no longer there.
The same problem occured using WildFly 21.

I tried then another approach using the code below:

```
// defined as a class member:
String credentialStoreConfigPath = "/opt/wildfly/standalone/data/credentials/jbcsstore.jceks"


public void putPassword(final String credentialAlias, final String password) throws CredentialStoreException {

    String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd " +this.wildFlyBinFolderPath };
    executeCommand(cmd);
    
    String [] command = {"./elytron-tool.sh credential-store --location " + Constants.TWO_DOTS + credentialStoreConfigPath + " --password "+ (wildFlyCredStorePasswordHere) + " --add " + credentialAlias + " --secret " + password};

    executeCommand(command);
}

private void executeCommand(String [] command) {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StreamGobbler streamGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), System.out::println);
    Future<?> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);

    int exitCode;
    try {
        exitCode = process.waitFor();
        assert exitCode == 0;
        future.get(); // waits for streamGobbler to finish

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private Consumer<String> consumer;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream inputStream, Consumer<String> consumer) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines().forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

and altough the code gets executed without an exception, the password is actually not stored in the credential store.

But why?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem turned to be quite simple in my case. It was using the first approach as shown below

```
credentialStore.store("clearPassword", new PasswordCredential(clearPassword));
```

and just adding the line

```
credentialStore.flush();
```

This did "the magic" and the credentials are now permanently stored in the credential store file.